# Component Services Error Log - SQL Server Distributed Replay Client

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, sql-server, event-log, dcom

I am getting the following error on a Windows Server 2008 x64 R2 Virtual Machine install:

```
Log Name: System
Source: Distributed COM
Event ID: 10016
Level: Error
Date: 2/20/2013 8:22:14 AM  

The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{6DF8CB71-153B-4C66-8FC4-E59301B8011B}
 and APPID 
{961AD749-64E9-4BD5-BCC8-ECE8BA0E241F}
 to the user NT SERVICE\SQL Server Distributed Replay Client SID (S-1-5-80-3249811479-2167633679-2115734285-1138413726-166979568) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

The server in question does have SQL Server 2012 installed.

So here is what I have tried so far..

As the error log states, the SQL Server Distributed Relay Client user does not have Local Activation permissions to the COM server with the ID specified in the error log.

1. I opened Component Services via Start > search for Component Services.
2. I browse to DCOM Config and find the APPID {961AD749-64E9-4BD5-BCC8-ECE8BA0E241F}, which happens  to be DReplayController.
3. Right click on DReplayController and select Properties
4. Go to the Security Tab
5. Change Launch and Activation Permissions to Customize and select Edit.

Here is a screenshot of the permissions for this object

[image]

6. I click OK and close the Component Services window, but the issue is not resolved.

What am I missing here?   I have to admit this is my first time messing with any of the stuff in Component Services in Windows.

I should also mention that this error is being generated approx every 3 seconds in the system event log.   Obviously, by the end of the day I have thousands of event logs for this event.

When I look at Services on this machine, I do see a SQL Server Distributed Replay Client service that is started automatically when windows boots.   What exactly does this service do in the first place?   Is this used to cluster SQL servers (I am just guessing from the name)?   Would it be OK for me to turn off this service?   Do you think turning this service off would cause any issues?   The SQL server installed on this server is a standalone database, and the data is only being acccessed locally via a web application.

If anyone has any suggestions as to why I am getting this error and how to stop it, let me know.  Am I on the right track in terms of attempting to troubleshoot this problem?

Let me know if you need any further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit for answering this goes to Microsoft Support.

So the issue was due to the fact that the NT Service\SQL Server Distributed Replay Client user did not have local activation permissions in the Component Services dialog.   The original error message clearly stated that I needed to give local activation permissions to the SQL Server Distributed Replay Client, but it seems that I gave permissions to SQL Server Distributed Replay CONTROLLER instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Start -> Run -> Type -> DCOMCNFG, expand Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config.
2. Click View -> Detail -> Now you will get Application Name and Application ID in right side.
3. Scroll down and find the application ID {961AD749-64E9-4BD5-BCC8-ECE8BA0E241F} -> Right Click -> Properties and select the Security tab. [DREPLAYCONTROLLER]
4. Click Customize under "Launch & Activation Permission" -> click Edit -> Add in the account NT Service\SQL Server Distributed Replay Client and set local launch and local activation.
5. Restart the application Service linked to this Application ID or restart the server and monitor